# Google Webpage Translator Plugin Won't Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expressionengine, google-translate

I've been trying to install Google Webpage Translator for ages on our websites. I have attempted placing the code in the header template, footer template, a specific page. I have change the language of the browser and my whole computer.

Currently I am embedding the Javascript parts of the "plugin" from Google into the footer template and that footer template contains the html component of the plugin and is embedded into all of the other pages.

While it doesn't work at all it does load all the required js and css files for the Google Translator system to do it's job - I am out of ideas - any one got any suggestions?

Using CMS ExpressionEngine 2.5

Below is a screen shot of the javascript error:
[image]

Comment: Any error in the browser's javascript console?  If so please add to question.

Comment: The error is visible when you open Developer Tools/Console - it is a javascript error (using Firefox to get the error report)

Comment: Since you're embedding the plugin code into a CMS template have you tried inspecting the source of the resulting page to ensure it is still correct and unaltered?

Comment: Hey Adam, I have an everything is there as it should be it's just not working correctly. Seems to be conflicting with Google Maps API